# Trouble changing text of Kivy TextInput widget using id: raises error " AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

In trying to change the displayed text of a TextInput widget, I encountered this error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

It throws the error and the programme halts.
Error located in .py file, line 35.

This issue only comes into play when that specific line is in the code; otherwise it works.

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
import nibabel as nib
from kivy.garden.filebrowser import FileBrowser
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("stack-test2.kv")

class Tabs(TabbedPanel):

    def nOpen(self):
        npop = niiPop()
        npop.open()

class niiPop(Popup):

    pathVariable = ' '
    file = ' '

    def nProcessor(self):
        if len(self.ids.nFile.selection) == 1:
            niiPop.pathVariable = str(self.ids.nFile.selection[0])
            niiPop.file = nib.load(niiPop.pathVariable)
            displayHeader = TextInput(text = str(niiPop.file.header), readonly = True)
            self.ids.nFile.clear_widgets()
            self.ids.nFile.add_widget(displayHeader)
            niiPop.auto_dismiss = True
            self.ids.fld1.text = niiPop.pathVariable
        else:
            self.ids.nFile.filename = ''

class stackTest1(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Test app'
        return Tabs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = stackTest1()
    app.run()
```

.kv file:

```
<TabbedPanelStrip>:    

<Tabs>:
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: self.size[0] / 3

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Setup'
        id: tab1

        BoxLayout: 
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Label:
                        text: 'file import'
                        size_hint: (0.3, 0.2)
                    TextInput:
                        id: fld1
                        text: ' '
                        multiline: False
                        readonly: True
                        size_hint: (0.6, 0.2)
                    Button:
                        id: btn1
                        text: '...'
                        size_hint: (0.1, 0.2)
                        on_press: root.nOpen()

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab3'

<niiPop>:
    id: niiPop
    title: 'Select a file'
    size_hint: (0.8, 0.8) 
    auto_dismiss: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        FileBrowser:    
            id: nFile
            filters: ['*.nii'] 
            select_string: 'Select'
            on_success: root.nProcessor()
            on_canceled: root.dismiss()
```

Output error log:

```
self.ids.fld1.text = niiPop.pathVariable

  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The `id` you are using is defined for the `Tabs` widget, but you ar using it as though it were defined for the `niiPop` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem - AttributeError

```
self.ids.fld1.text = niiPop.pathVariable

  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

## Root Cause

The keyword, `self` always refer to the current widget i.e. `niiPop` The `id: fld1` is not defined in the `class niiPop()`. Therefore, your Kivy app threw the `AttributeError`.

## Solution

The following enhancements are required in the kv and py files to solve the problem.

### kv file

- Add a link between the `id: fld1` and an `ObjectProperty` in the class rule, `<Tabs>:`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<Tabs>:
    fld1: fld1    # link fld1 to OjectProperty
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: self.size[0] / 3

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Setup'
        ...
```

### py file

1. Use [`App.get_running_app()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app) function to get an instance of your app.
2. Use the keyword, `root` to get an instance of your app's root.
3. Use the automatically generated `ObjectProperty`, `fld1` to reference the `TextInput` instance.

#### Snippets - py file

```
class niiPop(Popup):
    ...

    def nProcessor(self):
        if len(self.ids.nFile.selection) == 1:
            ...
            App.get_running_app().root.fld1.text = niiPop.pathVariable
        else:
            self.ids.nFile.filename = ''
```

## Output

[image: Result]